# Access current highlight text by Electron

Tags: windows, macos, electron

Is there any way to get the currently highlighted text by the users?

I know there is the solution like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822960/get-selected-text-from-electron-webview) to teach you how to access the text from webview created by Electron.

However, I hope I can get the text from any software, maybe in Chrome, Word, etc..

I think this API currently does not support by Electron. Is there any suggestion to do the trick?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a selection clipboard in Electron. To manipulate it you need to pass selection to each method.

```
const {clipboard} = require('electron')
clipboard.writeText('Example String', 'selection')
console.log(clipboard.readText('selection'))
```

Comment: It doesn't meet my requirement. I want to access the `highlighted text` not the clipboard data.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `window.getSelection()` method.